# how to understand such shuffling data code in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am learning at `Numpy` and I want to understand such shuffling data code as following:

```
# x is a m*n np.array
# return a shuffled-rows array 
def shuffle_col_vals(x):
    rand_x = np.array([np.random.choice(x.shape[0], size=x.shape[0], replace=False) for i in range(x.shape[1])]).T
    grid = np.indices(x.shape)
    rand_y = grid[1]
    return x[(rand_x, rand_y)]
```

So I input an `np.array` object as following:

```
x1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                [5, 6, 7, 8],
                [9, 10, 11, 12],
                [13, 14, 15, 16]], dtype=int)
```

And I get a output of `shuffle_col_vals(x1)` like comments as following:

```
array([[ 1,  5, 11, 15],
       [ 3,  8,  9, 14],
       [ 4,  6, 12, 16],
       [ 2,  7, 10, 13]], dtype=int64)
```

I get confused about the initial way of `rand_x` and I didn't get such way in [numpy.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) 
And I have been thinking it a long time, but I still don't understand why `return x[(rand_x, rand_y)]` will get a shuffled-rows array.
If not mind, could anyone explain the code to me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In indexing Numpy arrays, you can take single elements. Let's use a 3x4 array to be able to differentiate between the axes:

```
In [1]: x1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
   ...:                [5, 6, 7, 8],
   ...:                [9, 10, 11, 12]], dtype=int)

In [2]: x1[0, 0]
Out[2]: 1
```

If you review [Numpy Advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), you will find that you can do more in indexing, by providing lists for each dimension. Consider indexing with `x1[rows..., cols...]`, let's take two elements.

Pick from the first and second row, but always from the first column:

```
In [3]: x1[[0, 1], [0, 0]]
Out[3]: array([1, 5])
```

You can even index with arrays:

```
In [4]: x1[[[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 1]]]
Out[4]:
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

`np.indices` creates a row and col array, that if used for indexing, give back the original array:

```
In [5]: grid = np.indices(x1.shape)

In [6]: np.alltrue(x1[grid[0], grid[1]] == x1)
Out[6]: True
```

Now if you shuffle the values of `grid[0]` col-wise, but keep `grid[1]` as-is, and then use these for indexing, you get an array with the values of the columns shuffled.

Each column index vector is `[0, 1, 2]`. The code now shuffles these column index vectors for each column individually, and stacks them together into `rand_x` into the same shape as `x1`.

Create a single shuffled column index vector:

```
In [7]: np.random.seed(0)
In [8]: np.random.choice(x1.shape[0], size=x1.shape[0], replace=False)
Out[8]: array([2, 1, 0])
```

The stacking works by (pseudo-code) stacking with `[random-index-col-vec for cols in range(x1.shape[1])]` and then transposing (`.T`).

To make it a little clearer we can rewrite i as `col` and use `column_stack` instead of np.array([... for col]).T:

```
In [9]: np.random.seed(0)
In [10]: col_list = [np.random.choice(x1.shape[0], size=x1.shape[0], replace=False)
                     for col in range(x1.shape[1])]

In [11]: col_list
Out[11]: [array([2, 1, 0]), array([2, 0, 1]), array([0, 2, 1]), array([2, 0, 1])]

In [12]: rand_x = np.column_stack(col_list)
In [13]: rand_x
Out[13]:
array([[2, 2, 0, 2],
       [1, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1]])

In [14]: x1[rand_x, grid[1]]
Out[14]:
array([[ 9, 10,  3, 12],
       [ 5,  2, 11,  4],
       [ 1,  6,  7,  8]])
```

Details to note:

- the example output you give is different from what the function you provide does. It seems to be transposed.
- the use of `rand_x` and `rand_y` in the sample code can be confusing when being used to the convention of x=column index, y=row index

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and informative answer, but after reviewing [Numpy Advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) I still get some puzzles about `for i in range(x1.shape[1])` in **initial of numpy.array**. If change `for i in range(x1.shape[1])` to  `for i in range(3)`, the **shape** of `rand_x` will be (4, 3) not (4,4). If change to `for i in range(2)`, the **shape** of `rand_x` will be(4, 2). So it is reasonable to think in this way that we use `range` way to change the **shape** of numpy.array.

Comment: Yes, `np.array([[some-col] for col in range(3)]).T` creates an array with 3 columns. It's a list comprehension that creates a list of 3 columns (which are also lists), and then forms an np.array from it. I've edited the answer to include some information about the creation of `rand_x`.

Answer (score 1):

See output:

```
import numpy as np


def shuffle_col_val(x):
    print("----------------------------\n   A    rand_x\n")
    f = np.random.choice(x.shape[0], size=x.shape[0], replace=False)
    print(f, "\nNow I transpose an array.")
    rand_x = np.array([f]).T
    print(rand_x)
    print("----------------------------\n    B    rand_y\n")
    print("Grid gives you two possibilities\n you choose second:")
    grid = np.indices(x.shape)
    print(format(grid))
    rand_y = grid[1]
    print("\n----------------------------\n  C  Our rand_x, rand_y:")
    print("\nThe order of values in the column CHANGE:\n  has random order\n{}".format(rand_x))
    print("\nThe order of values in the row NO CHANGE:\n  has normal order 0, 1, 2, 3\n{}".format(rand_y))
    return x[(rand_x, rand_y)]


x1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
               [5, 6, 7, 8],
               [9, 10, 11, 12],
               [13, 14, 15, 16]], dtype=int)
print("\n----------------------------\n  D   Our shuffled-rows: \n{}\n".format(shuffle_col_val(x1)))
```

Output:

```
   A    rand_x
[2 3 0 1] 
Now I transpose an array.
[[2]
 [3]
 [0]
 [1]]
----------------------------
    B    rand_y
Grid gives you two possibilities, you choose second:
[[[0 0 0 0]
  [1 1 1 1]
  [2 2 2 2]
  [3 3 3 3]]

 [[0 1 2 3]
  [0 1 2 3]
  [0 1 2 3]
  [0 1 2 3]]]
----------------------------
  C  Our rand_x, rand_y:
The order of values in the column CHANGE: has random order
[[2]
 [3]
 [0]
 [1]]
The order of values in the row NO CHANGE: has normal order 0, 1, 2, 3
[[0 1 2 3]
 [0 1 2 3]
 [0 1 2 3]
 [0 1 2 3]]
----------------------------
  D   Our shuffled-rows: 
[[ 9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16]
 [ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]]
```